# VS2017 makes display driver crash around 4pm if web browser is on

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, visual-studio-2017, amd-firepro

I got a weird display driver crash problem.

My computer is Dell T5810 with Windows 10. My display card is AMD FirePro W2100. My display would crash around 4pm if I got Visual Studio 2017 on with a web browser (Chrome and Firefox both triggered the problem). I was really frustrated by the problem as I cannot get a clue about this issue. I'm using two monitors. Sometimes the display driver would crash and enter a low-resolution mode. Sometimes both my monitors would just go dark then I have to reconnect the cables and it would come back working.

Summary of computer specification:

- OS:Windows 10 (version 1709, build 16299.785)
- RAM: 8G
- Display card: AMD FirePro W2100
- Visual Studio 2017 Community (latest)
- Browser: Chrome or Firefox

Symptom:

- Display driver crashed around 4pm if both VS2017 and web browser is running.

Event Viewer and Task Scheduler (020419):

- There are some update tasks scheduled around 4PM including GoogleUpdate, Flash Player Update.
- From the event viewer, it's got a warning around my crash time about low virtual memory condition from Resource-Exhaustion-Detector. However this warning repeated several times during the day.

Would you like to make some recommendation so that I could look into it?

Many thanks!

**Update 040419**

I've enabled automatic virtual memory. The crash still happened. This time I looked into the event log.

In [Application Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRzgl.png), at 03:35:20 PM the Desktop Windows Manager restarted, which seems to cause the display driver to fail at 03:35:21 PM in the system log.

In [System Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG3QK.png), Resource-Exhaustion-Detector reported low virtual memory. The log says:

> Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The
>   following programs consumed the most virtual memory: MsMpEng.exe
>   (6332) consumed 559591424 bytes, javaw.exe (27812) consumed 521973760
>   bytes, and devenv.exe (27640) consumed 476442624 bytes.

The total virtual memory seems to be 1.45GB,  while the virtual memory is automatically set to 8GB.

Comment: Are you aware that your 1709 installation is more than 5 months old?  You should increase the amount of virtual memory your system can use.  Allow it to automatically determine the size of the page file.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, I've set my virtual memory to automatic. I'll see how it goes. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

Have you got enough physical memory for both to be running? - *How much memory have you got installed?*

Have a look in the event viewer for either a reason for the crash or a clue as to what was running around that time.

Check the "Task Scheduler" to see if there are any tasks launching at around 4pm.

---

low virtual memory could indicate you are running low on disk storage space?  you have plenty of space free on your HDD?

Comment: Hi gjpio, thank you for your reply. I've updated the question, added some event viewer log and task scheduler status.

Comment: Hi gjpio, it seems that since I changed my disk storage to a new one I didn't turn on the automatic virtual option. I've set it to automatic and I'll see how it goes. Thank you for your reply!